# Node Sass does not yet support Windows 64-bit

Tags: node.js, webpack, sass, protractor, yarnpkg

I am running protractor UI automation project and try to run test with `yarn test` and received following build error

`Module build failed: Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime`

I am on Windows 10 (64). below are the related entries in `package.json`

`"sass-lint": "^1.10.2",
"sass-loader": "6.0.6",
"sasslint-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.4",
"node-sass": "^4.0.0"`

`npm - 5.6.0
node - v9.11.1
yarn - 1.5.1`

```
{
  "name": "Avatarwebapps",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "description": "Avatar Apps",
  "private": true,
  "author": "Avatar DST",
  "sasslintConfig": ".sass-lint.yml",
  "contributors": [
    "Brian Kinch<brian.finch@Avatar.com.au>"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/Avatartest/Avatar.Digital.Apps.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://Avatartest.atlassian.net/"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf node_modules",
    "docs": "typedoc --options typedoc.json src/app/app.component.ts",
    "e2e": "protractor protractor.e2e.conf.js --params.environment",
    "smoke": "protractor protractor.smoke.conf.js --params.environment",
    "css:local:test": "cd backstop/development/maui && backstop test",
    "css:local:approve": "cd backstop/development/maui && backstop approve",
    "extractCustomer": "node extractCustomer.js",
    "lint:ts:fix": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json --fix",
    "lint:ts": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
    "lint:sass": "sass-lint -v",
    "lint:cpd": "rimraf reports/cpd && mkdir reports/cpd && jscpd -o reports/cpd/report.json -l 20 --limit 10 > reports/cpd/report.txt",
    "postinstall": "yarn webdriver:update && npm rebuild node-sass",
    "server": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack/webpack.config.myaccount.js --inline --progress --port 8080 --https --cert ./ssl/server.crt --key ./ssl/server.key",
    "start:e2e": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack/webpack.config.e2e.js --inline --quiet --https --port 8080",
    "build": "rimraf dist/non-prod && webpack --config config/webpack/webpack.config.build.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "build:e2e": "rimraf config/dist && webpack --config config/webpack/webpack.config.localhost.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "build:prod": "rimraf dist/prod && webpack --config config/webpack/webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "build:prod:analysis": "rimraf dist/prod && webpack --config config/webpack/webpack.config.prod.analyzer.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "build:aot": "rimraf aot/ dist/aot && node --max_old_space_size=6244 ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.aot.js --progress --profile --bail --display-error-details",
    "test": "karma start",
    "test:debug": "karma start --browsers Chrome",
    "test:ci": "karma start --browsers ChromeHeadless",
    "test:watch": "karma start --no-single-run --auto-watch",
    "test:watch:debug": "karma start --no-single-run --auto-watch --browsers Chrome",
    "test:mockserver": "ts-node ./server-ts/tests/runMockserverTests.ts",
    "webdriver:start": "webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update --ie",
    "webdriver:clean": "webdriver-manager clean",
    "build:service:nonprod": "rimraf dist/non-prod && webpack --config config/webpack/webpack.config.build-cache.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "build:dev:cache:nonprod": "yarn build:service:nonprod && yarn precache:nonprod && yarn server:nonprod",
    "build:cache:nonprod": "yarn build && yarn precache:nonprod",
    "build:cache:prod": "yarn build:prod && yarn precache:prod",
    "build:cache:aot": "yarn build:aot && yarn precache:aot",
    "server:aot": "node tools/simple-server.js",
    "server:aot:start:bg": "forever start -t -p . -al server.log tools/simple-server.js -p 8080",
    "server:aot:stop:bg": "forever stop tools/simple-server.js -p 8080",
    "precache:nonprod": "sw-precache --verbose --config=config/precacheConfig-nonprod.js",
    "precache:prod": "sw-precache --verbose --config=config/precacheConfig-prod.js",
    "precache:aot": "sw-precache --verbose --config=config/precacheConfig-aot.js",
    "mockserver": "ts-node-dev ./server-ts/index.ts",
    "mockserver:start:bg": "forever start -t -p . --workingDir . -al stub.log --id mockserver ./node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin.js ./server-ts/index.ts",
    "mockserver:stop:bg": "forever stop mockserver",
    "reports:plato": "yarn compile:ts && rimraf reports/plato && plato -r -d reports/plato -n -t \"My Account\" srcJs",
    "reports:complexity": "yarn compile:ts && rimraf reports/complexity && mkdir reports/complexity && cd srcJs && ../node_modules/jscomplexity/bin/jscomplexity-cli.js > ../reports/complexity/report.txt",
    "compile:ts": "rimraf srcJs && tsc -p src/tsc.json --outDir srcJs",
    "compile:e2e": "tsc --project e2etsc.json",
    "preflight": "yarn && yarn lint:sass && yarn lint:ts && yarn test:mockserver && yarn test:ci && yarn build:aot && yarn precache:aot && echo 'Preflight checks PASSED!' || echo 'Preflight checks FAILED!'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@typed/hashmap": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.16.8",
    "@types/express-fileupload": "^0.1.1",
    "angular-progress-http": "1.0.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.1",
    "angulartics2": "^2.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "css-element-queries": "^0.4.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.1.0",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.5.7",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.3.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.10.2",
    "@octopusdeploy/octopackjs": "0.0.7",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.40",
    "@types/express": "^4.11.0",
    "@types/form-data": "0.0.33",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.66",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.5",
    "@types/request": "^0.0.44",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.0",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
    "@types/webpack": "~3.8.11",
    "adal-node": "^0.1.27",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.2.3",
    "azure-keyvault": "^3.0.1-preview",
    "backstopjs": "^3.0.36",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.1",
    "chai": "^4.0.2",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^4.2.1",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "command-line-args": "^4.0.1",
    "command-line-usage": "^4.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "~4.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "ejs-compiled-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "express-fileupload": "^0.1.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "forever": "^0.15.3",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "git-rev-2": "^0.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.4",
    "inversify": "^4.10.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "jasmine-bamboo-reporter": "0.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.2.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "jscomplexity": "^2.0.0",
    "jscpd": "^0.6.15",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "jsonfile": "^3.0.0",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.4",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "mocha": "^3.1.2",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "^1.12.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.0.0",
    "ntypescript": "^1.201609302242.1",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "octopus-deploy": "^2.0.0",
    "open-browser-webpack-plugin": "0.0.3",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
    "optimize-js-plugin": "^0.0.4",
    "plato": "^1.7.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "protractor-browser-logs": "^1.0.351",
    "protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter": "0.0.7",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "sass-lint": "^1.10.2",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "sasslint-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.4",
    "should": "^11.1.1",
    "strip-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "sw-precache": "^5.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.3.3",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.2",
    "ts-mocks": "^0.2.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.16",
    "tslib": "^1.5.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "4.1.1",
    "tslint-loader": "3.5.3",
    "typedoc": "^0.7.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.8",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "3.11.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.11.0",
    "webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "zip-dir": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how protractor tests are related to node-sass

Comment: I use node-sass on Windows 10 64 bits with no problem at all. So maybe you have some other problem concerning yarn.

Comment: @muecas Can you please let me know which `node` and `npm` , `yarn` version you are using?

Comment: Please post your full package.json looks like you have a dependency issue. You should not run into this issue with the version of node you are on.

Comment: Node 9.3, npm 5.5.1 and node-sass 4.7.2 with libsass 3.5. Maybe you should update node packages or force to download the binaries again using `npm rebuild node-sass` prior to run yarn.

Comment: @Shaunak I have attached the `package.json`

Comment: That's a big package.json with dependencies on different versions of node-sass involved. When yarn errors out , it should create a `yarn-error.log`. Can you post that please? if it's too verbose just create a gist and link.  Updating all packages to latest would probably fix it, but with a project this large, unless you have a very good test harness, you may not want to do a full package upgrade.

Comment: @Shaunak please see here `https://gist.github.com/sudheerah/fc069a2a30ea7faac815c26d0af094ce`

Comment: I suspect its this include that's causing the break: https://gist.github.com/sudheerah/fc069a2a30ea7faac815c26d0af094ce#file-yarn-error-log-L7215   

Can you try to update just the node-sass module to latest?

Comment: @Shaunak I have tried few other version of `node-sass` , No luck though. Just curious does make any difference when install in project folder and global?

Comment: It should not, its safest to install locally in project folder anyway as there is no chance of conflicts.

Comment: One thing you can do is replace node-sass with sass. The sass package is 100% compatible with node-sass but is pure javascript (instead of binary module) so won't have any issues running on any platform that node runs on. I've successfully done this in my projects. All you need to do is trick npm by editing your package.json file. Where it says `node-sass` don't delete that line, instead replace `"node-sass": "^4.0.0",` with `"node-sass": "sass@1.59.3",` and then delete the node-sass folder in node_modules and do `npm install` again

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but didn't have to downgrade the node version. I just updated the package.json file node-sass entry to match my node version from the table on the github page. https://github.com/sass/node-sass/

I'm using node 14.15.3 so I put "node-sass": "^4.14.0" in dependencies, did another npm install, and it worked.